# Rotate elements in UML Designer

Tags: uml-designer

I am trying to make a relatively simple state machine in UML designer.
I was unable to rotate the "JOIN" object.

It appears horizontally, but I want it vertical.

[Please refer Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4nJJ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is not possible to rotate it. If you want to contribute this feature, UML Designer is open source, see http://www.umldesigner.org/developer-guide/contribute.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer sir/Ma'am . I am not a software professional. I found and try to study UML to communicate with my software engineer colleagues. I will surely demand their active participation in the development.